# layout menu items, change the style of the selected page 'Item'

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I'm trying to build a layout (master) menu, I want to mark the current page's link with different style

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink3" runat="server" style=" font-size:large; " class="specialeffects" NavigateUrl="~/ReclamationEncours.aspx">
    <strong>Reclamation Encours</strong>
</asp:HyperLink>
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" style=" font-size:large; " class="specialeffects" NavigateUrl="~/HistoriqueDeReclamation.aspx">
    <strong>Historique de reclamation</strong>
</asp:HyperLink>
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink2" runat="server" style=" font-size:large; " class="specialeffects" NavigateUrl="~/SuiviGTR.aspx">
    <strong>Suivi GTR</strong>
</asp:HyperLink>
```

Comment: Have you checked https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active? I assume that by "selected" you mean user puts focus on it (clicks or navigates to anchor element with keyboard)

Comment: thanks for your time , it's not working

Comment: Do you mean after it is clicked on?

Comment: yess whene i'm in ReclamationEncours page , i want to reclamation hyperlink color change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the following lines to the `Page_Load` methods of your pages:

```
var hyperLink = this.Master.FindControl("HyperLink3") as HyperLink;
hyperLink.ForeColor = Color.Green;
```

The lines above, for instance, should be added to the `Page_Load` of `ReclamationEncours.aspx` and so on.

Answer (score 3):

As I understood you want to mark the links that previously visited with a different color.

These links are marked as `visited` you can use this flag

this worked for me :

`a:visited {
    color: #F00;
}`

**--- UPDATE ---**

You can be done with this by mark the current link with `Active'.

We just compare the absolute current path.

Try this:

```
<li class="(@Request.Url.AbsolutePath== "/{sample}" ? "Active" : "")"><a href="samplePath> </a></li>
```

Then Add the style as you like:

```
li.active > a
li.active > a:hover
li.active > a:focus
```

Comment: not the previously visited , but the link that where i am

Comment: you mean the link you hover ? or you traying build menu

Comment: noooo not the hover , like this https://www.orange.ma/  you will see at the top "particuliers entreprise ..." when you in entreprise page , the color for the hyperlink will be orange

Comment: not working please check my quistion againe you will unerstand what i want

Comment: Okay,  Hmmm, I think there is another issue or misdescription. this way must match your requirements. Btw, the question was updated by me so that make sure I'm understanding what you want. lol. 
anyway, for curiosity when you find your answer please share it here

Comment: ooh that was youu , thanks , you will find the answer below .. thnks for your time

Answer (score 0):

using jquery you can switch the colors check [example](https://jsfiddle.net/pucbn81x/)

```
Html,JQUERY

    <a class="main current" href="#">test1</a>
    <a class="main" href="#">test2</a>
    <a  class="main" href="#">test3</a>
    <a  class="main" href="#">test4</a>

    $("a").click(function(){
    $("a").css('background-color', 'white');
    $("a").removeClass("current");
    $target = $(event.target);   
                $target.addClass('current');
    $('.current').css('background-color', 'red');
    });
```